# Ubuntu 20.04 USB port doesn't work right

Tags: ubuntu, usb, keyboard, mouse, dmesg

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my brand new Thinkpad E14 and it worked well until today.
I have 2 USB ports on my computer and they were working correctly a few days ago but now one of these 2 ports doesn't work right.
When i connect my Logitech keyboard to the faulty port it doesn't work at all, nothing lights up, even the CAPS lock or nothing.
When i connect my Logitech mouse to the faulty port, the optical red light underneath lights up BUT the mouse doesn't work.
The keyboard and the mouse both work on the other USB port that is working well.
Right now my keyboard is connected to the faulty port so it doesn't work and i'm using my mouse on the good USB port.
Here are the commands i tried out :

```
user@machine:$  lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 06cb:00fd Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:56ff IMC Networks Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

So here we can see the mouse that is connected on the good port and works well, it makes sense so far.

```
user@machine:$  usb-devices
T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 4
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=05.15
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 5.15.0-56-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=xxxx:xx:xx.3
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=02 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.01 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=13d3 ProdID=56ff Rev=19.19
S:  Manufacturer=Azurewave
S:  Product=Integrated Camera
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=03 Cnt=02 Dev#=  5 Spd=1.5 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=046d ProdID=c05a Rev=54.00
S:  Manufacturer=Logitech
S:  Product=USB Optical Mouse
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=98mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=10000 MxCh= 2
D:  Ver= 3.10 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=05.15
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 5.15.0-56-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=xxxx:xx:xx.3
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=03 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 4
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=05.15
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 5.15.0-56-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=xxxx:xx:xx.4
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=02 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=10 Prot=ff MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=06cb ProdID=00fd Rev=00.00
S:  SerialNumber=xxxxxxxxxxxx
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)

T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=03 Cnt=02 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.01 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=8087 ProdID=0029 Rev=00.01
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb

T:  Bus=04 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=10000 MxCh= 2
D:  Ver= 3.10 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=05.15
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 5.15.0-56-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=xxxx:xx:xx.4
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
```

Here we can only see the mouse, again makes sense because the other port is apparently faulty. BUT :

```
user@machine:$  dmesg | grep -i usb | grep -i logitech
[    1.624212] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    1.647355] input: Logitech USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:04:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:046D:C05A.0001/input/input9
[    1.647447] hid-generic 0003:046D:C05A.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:04:00.3-4/input0

[   93.925888] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Logitech
[   94.026389] input: Logitech USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:04:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:046D:C31C.0002/input/input17
[   94.084302] hid-generic 0003:046D:C31C.0002: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Logitech USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:04:00.3-4/input0

[   94.094272] input: Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:04:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:046D:C31C.0003/input/input18
[   94.152077] input: Logitech USB Keyboard System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:04:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:046D:C31C.0003/input/input19
[   94.152201] hid-generic 0003:046D:C31C.0003: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [Logitech USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:04:00.3-4/input1

[  141.788674] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Logitech
[  141.809029] input: Logitech USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:04:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:046D:C05A.0004/input/input20
[  141.809316] hid-generic 0003:046D:C05A.0004: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:04:00.3-4/input0
```

Here we can clearly see the mouse AND the keyboard, so in the end the faulty port works ?
I don't understand, i also tried to `apt update`and `apt upgrade` and even tried to reboot multiple times but it didn't work either.
What is going on and what can i do to make the faulty USB port work ?

Comment: you might have hardware newer than your OS has a chance to know. Why did you install 20.04 instead of 22.04? Both are LTS, but 22.04 is going to be supported two years longer, and is two years less old.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, i installed 20.04 instead of 22.04 because some of the software i'm using are not compatible with 22.04 just yet. The fact that the OS would be the problem doesn't seem plausible to me as the other USB port on the same computer works just fine with both the mouse and the keyboard

Comment: that's actually why I assume it's a software issue!